# How to fix NDK issues in VSCODE?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-ndk

I've installed NDK manually in my andriod studio. But still when i'm trying to run my app in VSCODE, it's showing the below msg of installing NDK. Can anyone give me a proper solution for it, please?[NDK INSTALLED ANDRIOD STUDIO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFlT3.png)

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
main.dart:1
[CXX1101] NDK at C:\Users\A.B.S.R\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk\23.1.7779620 did not have a source.properties file
Checking the license for package NDK (Side by side) 23.1.7779620 in C:\Users\A.B.S.R\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses
License for package NDK (Side by side) 23.1.7779620 accepted.
Preparing "Install NDK (Side by side) 23.1.7779620 (revision: 23.1.7779620)".